# Questions about the proof regarding the relationship between convergence in measure and convergence almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory

My question is about the proof of the statement:

> If $X_{n} \rightarrow_{\mu} X,$ then for some $n_{k}$ we have
> $X_{n_{k}} \rightarrow_{a . e .} X$.

**Proof:**

For any $k=1,2, \cdots,$ **choose** $n_{k}$ **such that for all** $n \geq n_{k}$ (1)
$$ 
\begin{array}{c}
\mu\left(\left|X_{n}-X\right|>1 / 2^{k}\right)<1 / 2^{k} \\
\text { Denote } B_{m} \equiv \cup_{k=m}^{\infty} A_{k} \equiv \cup_{k=m}^{\infty}\left\{\omega:\left|X_{n_{k}}-X\right|>1 / 2^{k}\right\}
\end{array}
$$
then we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mu\left(B_{m}\right) & \leq \sum_{k=m}^{\infty} \mu\left(A_{k}\right) \\
&<\sum_{k=m}^{\infty} 1 / 2^{k} \\
&=1 / 2^{m-1}
\end{aligned}
$$
Let $C \equiv \cup_{m=1}^{\infty} B_{m}^{c} .$ Then,
$$
\mu\left(C^{c}\right)=\mu\left(\cap_{m=1}^{\infty} B_{m}\right)
$$
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\leq \limsup \mu\left(B_{m}\right) \\
\leq \lim 1 / 2^{m-1} \\
=0
\end{array}
$$
**For $\omega \in C,$ there exists an $m$ such that $\omega \in B_{m}^{c}=\cap_{k=m}^{\infty} A_{k}^{c} .$ Hence, $\mid X_{n_{k}}(\omega)-X\left(\omega) \mid \leq 1 / 2^{k}\right.$ for all $k .$ Therefore, we have $X_{n_{k}}(\omega) \longrightarrow X(\omega)$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$** (2).

---

I have questions regarding the highlighted part.

1. (1) are we choosing $n_{k}$ such that for all $n \geq n_{k}$ so that when $k\rightarrow \infty$,$n_k\rightarrow\infty$?
   (2) it seems to me the $|x_n-X|>1/2^k$ is the bit redundant. Can I modify the proof as choose $n_k$ such that for all $n\geq n_k$, $\mu(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)<1/2^k$.
2. Can I simply say $\mu(C^c)=0$ which means the divergent set has measure 0? The last sentence confuses me. If $\omega\in C,\exists m_0$ so that $\omega\in B^c_m=\cap^\infty_{k=m} A^c_k=\cap\{w:|X_{n_k}-X|\leq 1/2^k\}$, which means for any $k\geq m_0$,$|X_{n_k}-X|\leq 1/2^k$, but it is true for $k\geq m_0$, how is it also true for $\forall k$?

---

I came up with the first question because in the textbook we were introduced to the proposition:

> Consider finite measurable $X_{n}$ 's and a finite measurable $X$.
>
> 1. We have $X_{n} \rightarrow_{\text {a.e.}} X$ if and only if
>    $$
>    \mu\left(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{m=n}^{\infty}\left[\left|X_{m}-X\right| \geq \varepsilon\right]\right)=0, \text { for all } \varepsilon>0
>    $$
> 2. (Most useful criterion for $\rightarrow_{a . e .}$ ) When $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$, we have $X_{n} \rightarrow_{a . e .} X$ if and only if
>    $$
>    \mu\left(\cup_{m=n}^{\infty}\left[\left|X_{m}-X\right| \geq \varepsilon\right]\right) \longrightarrow 0, \text { for all } \varepsilon>0
>    $$
>    Proof.
>    $$\left[X_{n} \rightarrow X\right]^{c}=\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{m=n}^{\infty}\left[\left|X_{m}-X\right| \geq \frac{1}{k}\right] \equiv \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k} (*)$$
>    $ \Longrightarrow$. From $(*),$ we have
>    $$
>    \begin{array}{l}
>    \mu\left(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{m=n}^{\infty}\left[\left|X_{m}-X\right| \geq \varepsilon\right]\right) \\
>    \leq \mu\left[\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{m=n}^{\infty}\left(\left|X_{m}-X\right| \geq \frac{1}{k}\right)\right] \\
>    =\mu\left(\left[X_{n} \rightarrow X\right]^{c}\right)=0
>    \end{array}
>    $$
>    $\Longleftrightarrow$ Again, we have from (*)
>    $$
>    \begin{aligned}
>    \mu\left(\left[X_{n} \rightarrow X\right]^{c}\right) &=\mu\left[\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{m=n}^{\infty}\left(\left|X_{m}-X\right| \geq \frac{1}{k}\right)\right] \\
>    & \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu\left[\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{m=n}^{\infty}\left(\left|X_{m}-X\right| \geq \frac{1}{k}\right)\right]=0
>    \end{aligned}
>    $$

Up to $\mu(C^c)=0$ we didn't use much of $(|X_n-X|>1/2^k)$, to me $1/2^k$ can be any number. My first impression is that the proof is an application of the proposition. The problem is that in the proposition $\epsilon$ can be any positive value, but in this proof, $n_k$ varies with the choice of $k$, when $k\rightarrow \infty$ then $n_k\rightarrow \infty$. So I cannot simply say $\mu(C^c)=0$, therefore, $X_{n_k}\rightarrow_{a.e}X$ by proposition.

But if I take $n_k$ such that for all $n\geq n_k$, $\mu(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)<1/2^k$, the problem seems to be solved because $\mu(C^c)=0$ regardless of the choice of $\epsilon$, which can be any non-negative number. Also,$\forall k>0,\epsilon>0,\exists n_k$.

I feel my thinking overlooked some important things but I can't know. I don't think it is correct but I wish someone could point out the flaw in my reasoning... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second question: If $a_k$ is a sequence of real numbers and you know $|a_k - a| \le 1/2^k$ for all $k \ge 100$, then you can conclude $a_k \to a$. It doesn't matter that $|a_k - a| \le 1/2^k$ might not be true for $k < 100$. This is exactly the argument used to go from "$|X_{n_k}(\omega) - X(\omega)| \le 1/2^k$ for $k \ge m_0$" to "$X_{n_k}(\omega) \to X(\omega)$."

For your first question: the $\epsilon$ must vary with $k$. If you choose the same $\epsilon$ for each $n_k$, then you end up with $|X_{n_k}(\omega) - X(\omega)| \le \epsilon$ for $k \ge m_0$ which isn't enough to conclude convergence.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your prompt response! I have added details of my reasoning. Could you please take a look if you don't mind? I am confused and cannot tell where I have made mistakes

Comment: @JoZ I think the difficulty of directly using that proposition here is due to the "for all $\epsilon > 0$" condition. In your proposed argument, the sequence $n_k$ would change every time you choose a different $\epsilon$.

Comment: I see. It is very helpful. So I should not view this proof as an application of the proposition and the idea of the proof is to construct a subsequence $X_{n_k}$ satisfying the definition of convergence almost everywhere? I.e. $\mu{C^c}=0$ suggests that the divergent set has measure 0 and we see when $n_k\rightarrow\infty$, the distance approaches to 0.